# Java heap size is growing up permanently when I use Hazelcast Jet

Tags: java, hazelcast, hazelcast-jet

My stream is not quite big. I'm transferring about 400 KB of data every 2 seconds through the Jet pipeline. [image]

I'm using buffer maps to initiate a stream by event journal with this configuration:

```
    config.getMapEventJournalConfig(Constants.IMAP_TAGS_INFO_BUFFER)
        .setEnabled(true)
        .setCapacity(100)
        .setTimeToLiveSeconds(10);
    config.getMapEventJournalConfig(Constants.IMAP_TAGS_POSITIONS_BUFFER)
        .setEnabled(true)
        .setCapacity(100)
        .setTimeToLiveSeconds(10);
```

The pipeline begins at:

```
StreamStage<Map.Entry<String, List<TagPosition>>> sourceSteam = p.drawFrom(Sources.mapJournal(
            Constants.IMAP_TAGS_POSITIONS_BUFFER,
            Util.mapPutEvents(),
            Util.mapEventToEntry(),
            JournalInitialPosition.START_FROM_OLDEST))
```

The setting of new values in buffer maps is performed by method set() with replacement an old value.

And after several hours of running my application reaches xmx value and Hazelcast will shut down.

[image]

Could you please check if I have wrong configuration or I should profile my application more detailed? My current assumption is that the event's journal is not cleaned despite on setting capacity and time to live.

Thanks in advance!

UPD: added heap dump and diagram

[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't think it's related, but a capacity of 100 is incorrect. The capacity should be a multiple of the number of partitions (see https://docs.hazelcast.org/docs/3.10.5/javadoc/com/hazelcast/config/EventJournalConfig.html#setCapacity-int-) and the number of partitions should be a prime number.

Comment: Oh thanks Neil! I didn't get this. I thought that it is a capacity of storage which contains history of events.

Comment: Yes you should use a larger number, much larger than the number of partitions (default 271). What are you doing with the items afterwards? Could they be accumulating somewhere else?

Comment: As you can see on the first image I have third map which contains historical data and is cleaned periodically (around each 30-60 secs). Also there are several sinks (1 - websocket, rest of them - database sinks) and one processor in front of one of sinks.

Comment: I think you need to have a look on heap dump. We are not aware of a memory leak issue, I'd say it's a misconfiguration.

Comment: ... added heap dump

Comment: I want to add that I've disabled pipeline processing part of application and left just putting data to buffer maps. In that case the memory usage was OK. Will try to overview the disabled a bit later.